# How to allow a generic type parameter for a C# method to accept a null argument?

Tags: c#, generics, .net-4.0

```
private static Matcher<T> EqualTo<T>(T item)
{
    return new IsEqual<T>(item);
}
```

How do I modify the above method definition such that the following are valid/allowed.

```
EqualTo("abc");
EqualTo(4);
EqualTo(null); // doesn't compile. EqualTo<string>(null) does
```

Trying to port some Java code where `null` seems to be acceptable value for a `T` parameter.

---

**Update**
Thanks: for all the answers - especially Eamon and Jason. I didn't want the method calls to bother with type-inference. The following overload fixed it.

```
    private static Matcher<object> EqualTo(object item)
    {
        return EqualTo<object>(item);
    }
```

Actually the above question was a part of a larger puzzle. The end goal was for the following to work.

```
        this.AssertThat(null, EqualTo(null));
        this.AssertThat(null, Not(EqualTo("hi")));
        this.AssertThat("hi", Not(EqualTo(null)));
```

Applied the same fix.. **RFC**. (Ignore the ugly extension method part - that's another problem. Wanted to have these methods in all test-fixtures without inheritance.)

```
public static void AssertThat<T>(this object testFixture, object actual, Matcher<T> matcher, string message = "")
{
  AssertThat(anyObject, (T)actual, matcher, message);
}

public static void AssertThat<T, TSuper>(this object testFixture, T actual, Matcher<TSuper> matcher, string message = "") where T : TSuper
{
  ... check and assert
```

Comment: How would you expect it to infer the type T from an explicit null value?  You can certainly use it on a null value in a string variable, but I don't know of any way to infer a type from an explicit null without specifying it manually.

Comment: Well, you might expect it to infer `object`.

Comment: And what's wrong with `EqualTo<string>(null)` ?  I'm trying to see the _practical_ problem.

Comment: @Eamon - at the very least that seems like a way to allow people to create bugs.  I don't know enough about the signature of `Matcher<T>` but I can think of several things this would break in a fluent style interface by changing the type of the result without warning.

Comment: @tvanfosson - actually that is exactly what I'd like in my specific scenario - See update. @Eamon - thanks for sending me on my way. I kinda figured it out while the other answers were being posted. :)

Comment: @Gishu - my point was that the compiler, in this instance, can't safely guess what it is that you want so it makes you choose.  Doing `EqualTo((object)null)` explicitly tells the compiler (and the reader) exactly what you mean.

Comment: @tvanfosson - :) Sorry didn't mention that! I understood why the compiler refused to compile that bit without an explicit type-inference nudge. I just wanted the API to work in an intuitive way.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Consider the following method:

```
public bool IsNullString<T>(T item) {
    return typeof(T) == typeof(string) && item == null;
}
```

Yes, this is a pathetically stupid method and using generics is pointless here, but you'll see the point in a moment.

Now consider

```
bool first = IsNullString<string>(null);
bool second = IsNullString<Foo>(null);

bool third = IsNullString(null);
```

In the first and second, the compiler can clearly distinguish the type of `T` (no inference is needed). In the third, how the compiler infer what `T` is? In particular, it can't distinguish between `T == string` and `T == Foo`, or any other type for that matter. Therefore, the compiler has to give you a compile-time error.

If you want to get around this, you either need to cast `null`

```
EqualTo((object)null);
```

or explicitly state the type

```
EqualTo<object>(null)
```

or define an overload

```
private static Matcher<object> EqualTo(object item) {
    return new IsEqual<object>(item);
}
```

Comment: the last bit was exactly what I ended up using. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Not possible without explicitly specifying a T or doing a cast. Generics are compile time constructs and as such if the compiler can't figure out the type at compile time, then it won't compile (as you're seeing).

Answer (score 2):

Since you can't do exactly what you are wanting to do, how about defining an `EqualTo(object)` overloaded method? That should allow your required syntax.

Answer (score 2):

You may work around this limitation by using the following syntax:

```
EqualTo("abc");
EqualTo(4);
EqualTo(default(object));
//equivalently:
EqualTo((object)null);
```

`default(T)` is the value a field of type `T` has if not set.  For reference types, it's `null`, for value types it's essentially memory filled with zero bytes (...which may mean different things for different types, but generally means some version of zero).

I try to avoid the `null`  everywhere in my code nowadays.  It hampers type inference elsewhere too, such as with the `var` declared field and in a ternary operator.  For example,  `myArray==null ? default(int?) : myArray.Length` is OK, but `myArray==null ? null : myArray.Length` won't compile.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe implementing a non-generic EqualTo, which takes an Object as the argument type, would solve the issue of rewriting those code lines.